# visual studio xamarin forms mvvm

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm starting a new project, and id like to use MVVM - I really like this pattern, and I have been using it in all my windows phone 8.1 apps. But moving to xamarin is a jungle! I usually use mvvm light, and I have a nice basic implementation I use every time a create a new project - but I can't find a really good sample that shows exactly what I need. 
What I want to do is make a xamarin shared (or portable) project, that shares the views across all platforms. I want to write create the view using code-behind - so no xaml.
Does anyone have experience with this and can point me to a good sample?
I'm also wondering if I need to use a thirtyparty framework afterall, since navigating seems pretty easy.

Comment: Why would you want do this? Main advantage of XAML is fast and easy designing UI and easy bindings

Comment: I don't like XAML. I prefer to use one language as much as possible. IMHO it's easier to maintain in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

There are many samples on to be found. My favorite site for Xamarin.Forms samples is [Xamarin Forms in Anger](https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-in-anger/).

Let's take a look at the [Jobbberr sample](https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-in-anger-jobbberr/):

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace InAnger.Jobbberr
{
    public class SettingsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SettingsPage ()
        {
            Style = AppStyle.SettingsPageStyle;

            var pageTitle = new Frame () {
                Style = AppStyle.PageTitleLabelFrameStyle,
                Padding = new Thickness(0,Device.OnPlatform(15,0,0),0,10),
                Content = new Label { 
                    Style = AppStyle.PageTitleLabelStyle,
                    Text = "Settings",
                }
            };

            var signoutButton = new Button () {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Text = "Sign Out",
                TextColor = AppStyle.DarkLabelColor,
            };

            Content = new StackLayout {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Padding = new Thickness (20),
                Children = {
                    pageTitle,
                    new BoxView() {
                        HeightRequest = 1,
                        BackgroundColor = AppStyle.DarkLabelColor,
                    },
                    new SettingsUserView(),
                    new SyncView (),
                    new SettingsSwitchView ("GPS"),
                    new SettingsSwitchView ("Jobs Alert"),
                    signoutButton,
                    new StatusBarView()
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**What do you see here?**

The new class `SettingsPage` derives from `ContentPage`. The controls `pageTitle` and `signoutButton` are created in its constructor. In the end you see how a `StackLayout` is being created, filled with the controls and set as content of the page. That's how to create a `Page` in code.

**How to apply MVVM?**

1. Set `BindingContext = ViewModel` in the first row of the constructor (create a new view model or locate it by via a `ViewModelLocator` or anything).
2. Let's say for example you want to bind the `Text` and `Command` property of `signoutButton` to the view model's properties `SignOutButtonText` and `SignoutCommand`. You would change the creation of the button to this:

   ```
   var signoutButton = new Button () {
       VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
       HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
       TextColor = AppStyle.DarkLabelColor,
   };

   signoutButton.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, "SignOutButtonText");
   signoutButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, "SignoutCommand");
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not aware of the Forms in Anger :) been looking into it, and trying stuff out - it's very nice. My problem is not making a simple MVVM application, but when it comes to navigating - and passing parameters between viewmodels - it gets complicated. My solution for now, is to pass the parameter to the view, and then perform the operation i need on the viewmodel, add data etc, But i kinda feel like i break the pattern here - since there is a higher coupling. Normally i would have the view implement a navigation interface to the viewmodels constructor.